# set_clip_path make plot out side the axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I want to plot contourf inside a country shape. So I use the following code:

```
def get_geometries(*readers):
    geoms = []
    for reader in readers:
        for record in reader.records():
            geoms += [record.geometry]
    return geoms

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
ax.set_extent([100, 140, 15, 60], crs=proj)

reader = Reader('*.shp')

geoms = get_geometries(reader)
ax.add_geometries(geoms, proj, edgecolor='black',
                  facecolor='none', alpha=0.5)

contour = ax.contourf(gx, gy, grid_data, cmap=cmap, levels=levels, extend='both')
# mask the contour plot outside the shape file
path = Path.make_compound_path(*geos_to_path(geoms))
patch = mpatches.PathPatch(path, transform=ax.transData)
for col in contour.collections:
    col.set_clip_path(patch)
```

But it turns out that if I use the `set_clip_path` function, the `ax.set_extent` will not be effective. If I comment the last four lines of code, the `ax.set_extent` is useful.

I guess there are some changes in Cartopy or Matplotlib. Because this code worked well before.

Thank you[image]

Comment: I wonder if this is related to https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1620 Can you try with the current master branch?